# In Jenkins pipeline Groovy, how can I set a value as a quoted string in a YAML file?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following code that updates values in a Yaml file

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

String version = "1.0.0"
def data = readYaml file: "Chart.yaml"
data.name = "myApp"
// The version needs to be in double-quotes
data.appVersion = "\"${version}\""
sh "rm Chart.yaml"
writeYaml file: "Chart.yaml", data: data
sh "cat Chart.yaml"
```

So I need the `Chart.yaml` file to have

```
appVersion = "1.0.0"
```

However, the above code puts this, with the extra single-quotes.

```
appVersion = '"1.0.0"'
```

Same result for

```
data.appVersion = '"'+version+'"'
```

If I just have this

```
data.appVersion = "${version}" // just string interpolation in this case
```

then of course I get this, with no quotes

```
appVersion = 1.0.0
```

Comment: I'm afraid you have to do some magic afterwards as the writeYaml step does not change the scalar style (from what I've seen/read). You can however change it to `DOUBLE_QUOTED` scalarstyle (using NonCSP and set that explicitly), but then everything will be double quoted: `"appVersion": "1.0.0"`. Unfortunately booleans in your yaml file will also be transformed as `"name": !!bool "false"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing based on Unforgetable631's suggestion.

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

String version = "1.0.0"
def data = readYaml file: "Chart.yaml"
data.name = "myApp"
// The version needs to be in double-quotes
data.appVersion = version
sh "rm Chart.yaml"
writeYaml file: "Chart.yaml", data: data
sh """
  cat Chart.yaml
  sed -i \"s/$version/\\"$version\\"/g\" Chart.yaml
  cat Chart.yaml
"""
```